# function find.mle() hangs in R package diversitree

Tags: r, phylogeny

I am trying to do an analysis using the `diversitree` package in R.

I am trying to analyze a phylogeny of the Rosaceae using a number of different combinations of models in order to parse out the significance level of the output from a different analysis that I did in `MuSSE`. I am discovering, however, that certain combinations of characters cause R to apparently crash - it becomes unresponsive, and an analysis that normally takes about a minute never completes.

The code, along with the problematic lines, is as follows:

```
setwd("MyWd")
require(diversitree)
mytree = read.nexus("BEAST_Rosales_final.nex")
nopoly = multi2di(mytree, random=TRUE)
pruned = drop.tip(nopoly, "Pseudolmedea")
pruned = drop.tip(pruned, "Zizyphus")
nopoly = multi2di(mytree, random=TRUE)
chardata = read.csv("Chapter_2_BiSSE.csv", header=TRUE)

statesD = chardata$D
statesW = chardata$W
statesR = chardata$R
statesS = chardata$S
statesDW = chardata$DW
statesDR = chardata$DR
statesDS = chardata$DS
statesWR = chardata$WR
statesWS = chardata$WS
statesRS = chardata$RS
statesDWR = chardata$DWR
statesDWS = chardata$DWS
statesDRS = chardata$DRS
statesWRS = chardata$WRS
statesDWRS = chardata$DWRS

names(statesD) = chardata$Genus
names(statesW) = chardata$Genus
names(statesR) = chardata$Genus
names(statesS) = chardata$Genus
names(statesDW) = chardata$Genus
names(statesDR) = chardata$Genus
names(statesDS) = chardata$Genus
names(statesWR) = chardata$Genus
names(statesWS) = chardata$Genus
names(statesRS) = chardata$Genus
names(statesDWR) = chardata$Genus
names(statesDWS) = chardata$Genus
names(statesDRS) = chardata$Genus
names(statesWRS) = chardata$Genus
names(statesDWRS) = chardata$Genus

likD = make.bisse(pruned, statesD)
likW = make.bisse(pruned, statesW)
likR = make.bisse(pruned, statesR)
likS = make.bisse(pruned, statesS)
likDW = make.bisse(pruned, statesDW)
likDR = make.bisse(pruned, statesDR)
likDS = make.bisse(pruned, statesDS)
likWR = make.bisse(pruned, statesWR)
likWS = make.bisse(pruned, statesWS)
likRS = make.bisse(pruned, statesRS)
likDWR = make.bisse(pruned, statesDWR)
likDWS = make.bisse(pruned, statesDWS)
likDRS = make.bisse(pruned, statesDRS)
likWRS = make.bisse(pruned, statesWRS)
likDWRS = make.bisse(pruned, statesDWRS)
lik0 = constrain(likDWRS, lambda1 ~ lambda0, mu1 ~ mu0, q10 ~ q01)

startp = starting.point.bisse(pruned)

fit0 = find.mle(lik0, startp[argnames(lik0)])           #not problematic
fitD = find.mle(likD, startp[argnames(likD)])           #not problematic
fitW = find.mle(likW, startp[argnames(likW)])           #not problematic
fitR = find.mle(likR, startp[argnames(likR)])           #not problematic
fitS = find.mle(likS, startp[argnames(likS)])           #not problematic
fitDW = find.mle(likDW, startp[argnames(likDW)])           #not problematic
fitDR = find.mle(likDR, startp[argnames(likDR)])           #not problematic
fitDS = find.mle(likDS, startp[argnames(likDS)])           #problematic!
fitWR = find.mle(likWR, startp[argnames(likWR)])           #not problematic
fitWS = find.mle(likWS, startp[argnames(likWS)])           #problematic!
fitRS = find.mle(likRS, startp[argnames(likRS)])           #not problematic
fitDWR = find.mle(likDWR, startp[argnames(likDWR)])           #not problematic
fitDWS = find.mle(likDWS, startp[argnames(likDWS)])           #problematic!
fitDRS = find.mle(likDRS, startp[argnames(likDRS)])           #problematic!
fitWRS = find.mle(likWRS, startp[argnames(likWRS)])           #problematic!
fitDWRS = find.mle(likDWRS, startp[argnames(likDWRS)])           #problematic!

summary(fit0)
summary(fitD)
summary(fitW)
summary(fitR)
summary(fitS)
summary(fitDW)
summary(fitDR)
summary(fitDS)
summary(fitWR)
summary(fitWS)
summary(fitRS)
summary(fitDWR)
summary(fitDWS)
summary(fitDRS)
summary(fitWRS)
summary(fitDWRS)

AIC(fit0, fitD, fitW, fitR, fitS, fitDW, fitDR, fitDS, fitWR, fitWS, fitRS, fitDWR, fitDWS, fitDRS, fitWRS, fitDWRS)
```

The lines responsible for the trouble are noted with comments. I observe that of my 253 terminal tips, all of the lines that cause problems have only about 50 of those tips have one character state, while the other 200-odd have the other state. It does not matter which state I code as state 0 or state 1.

Can anybody tell me what problem is?

Comment: It seems like the clues to your problem are in the data, can you provide access to the data and/or provide a minimum reproducible example?